# How to reuse grease pencil object?

Tags: grease-pencil

I draw an object with grease pencil, then bind to bones.

[image: origin file]

then I append it in another file, but its color changes, and it cannot be edited neither.

[image: in another file]

Is there a way to reuse them?

Comment: Solved. After appending GP object, a keyframe is inserted automatically. Before the keyframe , the object displays its blue shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that viewport color is material, not random:

[image]

And check if Grease pencil layers are not affected by the lights (use lights unchecked):

[image]

Then linking, make sure that you are linking a collection with GP object, not the object itself and then after linking, use option Object → Relations → Make Library Override to get an ability to move and animate bones.